# Require duplicate Primary Keys in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm aware that I can't have duplicate primary keys in any database but cassandra limits my ability to query on only 1 of the keys in a compound primary key.

my use case is as follows:

```
File 1
    variableA
    variableB
    variableC

File 2
    variableC
    variableD
    variableE
```

I want to create tables as follows:

```
variables
==================
variable_id PK
file_id     PK
UUID        PK

files
==================
file_id     PK
...other_columns
```

I'm parsing the files and inserting the variables into the variables table. 
Later, I want to find all files with variableC. However, while I have the file_id when I'm creating the record, I do not have the file_id during query. Unlike other db's cassandra requires that I provide both PK's in my query. This is not possible.

I need some ideas on how to overcome this modeling problem.

There will be, potentially, trillions of variables so ALLOW FILTERING and secondary indexes are not an option. This cannot possibly be a unique use case. How have others overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have duplicate primary keys in Cassandra (and also not in relational databases as well).

But you could store for every variable_id the file_ids where the variable is included, for example:

Use (variable_id, file_id) as primary key and store a timestamp or if the variable is only included once in every file the actual value in this table. Remember variable_id is the partition key and file_id is the cluster column in this case. So you can query easily all file_ids and values for a given variable_id.

If this fits well depends on your use case. Maybe you will need to put the file_ids into bin if there are too much files. Or it might be a good idea to group them by day, month or some other criteria in order to prevent partitions becoming too large.

Comment: I'm aware of primary key restrictions. However, relation db's also allow you to query on non primary key columns. I cannot use the file_id in the primary key because, as I mentioned, I don't have access to the file_id when I'm looking up variables. I just want to find all variableC's. This doesn't seem possible in Cassandra, which is a serous issues for us.

Comment: You can use (variable_id, file_id) as primary key. You do have to know the partition key part of your primary key which is variable_id. So you can query "select * from table where variable_id=x".

Comment: Mandraenke, You are correct and somehow I missed the fact that the cluster portion of the primary key allows me to enter duplicate partition keys AND only query on the partition key. This is exactly what I need. Somehow, after watching 20 straight hours of Cassandra videos I brain farted on this fact. I decided not to delete my silly question in case others run into the same brain fart.

Comment: This is a tricky thing and pretty easy to miss indeed. CQL and SQL look fairly similar. But primary keys share the same name and some function as there is only one "value" per key BUT cassandra composes the primary key out of partition key and cluster colums. There are some good vidoes on datastax university for free helping to understand the data model.

Comment: Keep in mind, that data that shares the same partition key part of the primary key is located on the same cluster node. This can be helpful and speed things up, but also can lead to very large partitions which will cause problems. So maybe a primary key ((variable_id, date), file_id) might be better and allows you to get all data for a variable_id and date from a single node read (date could be a month also). Another issue from bad partition keys is hotspots when writes target a single node over a time (not in your case here). A good partition key should spread your data.